# how to calculate the following integral related to Chebyshev polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind $V_n(x)$ can be defined as
$$V_n(x)=\frac{\sin(n+1)\theta}{\sin\theta}, x=2\cos\theta$$
or through the recurrence relation
$$V_{n+1}=xV_n-V_{n-1}, V_0=1,  V_1=x.$$
First few low-order Chebyshev polynomials of the second
kind are as follows:
$$V_0=1, V_1=x,V_2=x^2-1,V_3=x^3-2x,$$
$$V_4=x^4-3x^2+1,V_5=x^5-4x^3+3x.$$

I want to know how to calculate the following integral relate to Chebyshev polynomials:
$$\int_0^\pi (\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x})^m dx$$
where $n,m\in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

It is easy to see the following result:

For an even number $n  \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and and odd number $m \in \mathbb{N}$, we have

$$ \int_0^\pi (\frac {\sin nx}{\sin x})^{m} dx=0.$$

I conjectured   that the result is a polynomial $P(n)$ of order $m−1$. But I have no idea about the proof.

I prefer to know the other two cases beside the above special case.   Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$I_{nm}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \left(\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}\right)^m dx$$

As stated in the OP, $I_{nm}=0$ for $n$ even and $m$ odd. 
Otherwise, the nonzero $I_{nm}$ is the *central multinomial coefficient* $c_{nm}$, the largest coefficient of $(1+x+x^2\cdots x^{n-1})^m$.

A few examples:
$$I_{44}=44\;\; \text{and}\;\; (1 + x + x^2 + x^3)^4=1 + \cdots + 40 x^5 + \mathbf{44}\, x^6 + 40 x^7 + 
 \cdots + x^{12}$$
$$I_{34}=19\;\; \text{and}\;\; (1 + x + x^2 )^4=1 + \cdots + 16 x^3 + \mathbf{19}\, x^4 + 16 x^5 + 
 \cdots + x^{8}$$
$$I_{33}=7\;\; \text{and}\;\; (1 + x + x^2 )^3=1 + 3 x + 6 x^2 + \mathbf{7}\, x^3 + 6 x^4 + 3 x^5 + x^6$$

For small $n$ the central multinomial coefficients are listed on [OEIS](https://oeis.org), for example, $I_{6m}$ is given for $m=2,4,6,8,\ldots$ by A063419:

<sub>$$ 6, 146, 4332, 135954, 4395456, 144840476, 4836766584, 163112472594, 5542414273884, 189456975899496, 6507792553644256, \ldots$$</sub>

An efficient method to calculate these coefficients is described in [On a link between Dirichlet kernels and central multinomial coefficients.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X15001260)

---

**Update 1**, following the conjecture added in a comment, that $I_{nm}=P_m(n)$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $m-1$; I have no proof, but for the record, here is the evidence for small $m$:

<sub>$$P_1(n)=1$$
$$P_2(n)=n$$
$$P_{3}(n)=\frac{1}{4} \left(3 n^2+1\right)$$
$$P_4(n)=\frac{1}{3} n\left(2 n^2+1\right)$$
$$P_{5}(n)=\frac{1}{192} \left(115 n^4+50 n^2+27\right)$$
$$P_6(n)=\frac{1}{20} n \left(11 n^4+5 n^2+4\right)$$
$$P_7(n)=\frac{7 \left(841 n^6+385 n^4+259n^2\right)+1125}{11520}$$
$$P_8(n)=\frac{1}{315} n \left(151 n^6+70 n^4+49 n^2+45\right)$$
$$P_9(n)=\frac{259723 n^8+121380 n^6+84882 n^4+64580 n^2+42875}{573440}$$
$$P_{10}(n)=\frac{1}{36288}n \left(15619 n^8+7350 n^6+5187 n^4+4100 n^2+4032\right)$$</sub>

For fixed *even* $m$, these formulas represent closed form expressions for the central multinomial coefficients $c_{nm}$. On OEIS I find that such polynomial expressions are noted by R.H. Hardin (see  [A071816](https://oeis.org/A071816) and [A005900](https://oeis.org/A005900)), but without a reference to a general proof.

For fixed *odd* $m$, only the $c_{nm}$'s with odd $n$ follow. I have checked that there is no degree $m-1$ polynomial expressions for the full set of central multinomial coefficients with odd $m$.

---

**Update 2**
I have now located a proof in the literature, see https://mathoverflow.net/a/313854/11260

Comment: @beenaker how to prove $I_{nm}$ is the largest coefficient of $(1+x+x^2\cdots x^{n-1})^m$.

Comment: @Beenakker Thanks a lot. Is there any formula on $I_{nm}$?

Comment: For the proof, just write $\sin(nx)/\sin x=(z^n-z^{-n})/(z-z^{-1)}=z^{n-1}+z^{n-3}+\dots+z^{1-n}=z^{1-n}f(z^2)$ for $z=e^{ix}$ and $f(w)=1+w+\dots+w^{n-1}$, expand the brackets and use the fact that $\int z^{2t}=0$ for $t\ne 0$.

Comment: @Petrov Nice to see you again. Thanks for the proof.

Comment: @Beenakker I conjecured that the $I_{nm}$ is a polynomial  $P(n)$ of order $m−1$ .

Comment: @beenakker  My conjecture, to be clearly, is that if $I_{nm}\neq 0,$ then $I_{nm}$ is a polynomial $P(n)$ of order $m-1.$ As above saying, when $n$ is even, $m$ is odd,  $I_{nm}=0.$  Hence $I_{23}=0, I_{43}=0.$  For $I_{13}=1 $and $I_{33}=7$, it admits  the polynomial $P_3(n)$ ,whose degree is 2.

Answer (score 1):

We use complex analysis, of course, standard way to convert an integral of a periodic function, integrated on a period.
In our case:
$$
\begin{aligned}
J(n,m)
&=
\int_0^\pi\left(\frac {\sin nt}{\sin t}\right)^m\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 12
\int_0^{2\pi}
\left(\frac {e^{int}-e^{-int}}{e^{it}-e^{-it}}\right)^m
\cdot\frac 1{e^{it}}\; ie^{it}\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 1{2i}
\int_\gamma
\left(\frac {z^{n}-z^{-n}}{z-z^{-1}}\right)^m\cdot\frac 1z\; 
\; dz
\\
&=
2\pi i\cdot\frac 1{2i}
\cdot\text{Residue of }
\frac 1z
\underbrace{\left(z^{n-1}+\dots z^{n-3}+\dots z^{-(n-3)}+z^{-(n-1)}\right)^m}_{P(n,m)}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Now we have to isolate the residue of the above integral on $\gamma$, the unit circle. We can simplify and need the coefficient of degree **zero** in 
$$
P(n,m)=\left(z^{n-1}+\dots z^{n-3}+\dots z^{-(n-3)}+z^{-(n-1)}\right)^m\ .
$$
From here, as in the answer of [Carlo Beenakker](https://mathoverflow.net/users/11260/carlo-beenakker) pointing to an OEIS.

Computer check in a special case.

```
sage: integral( ( sin(7*x) / sin(x) )^9, x, 0, pi )
2636263*pi
sage: var('z');
sage: P = (( z^6 + z^4 + z^2 + 1 + z^-2 + z^-4 + z^-6 )^9) / z
sage: P.residue(z)
2636263
sage: # also
```

Comment: Should it be the following ?$$
\begin{aligned}
J(n,m)
&=
\int_0^\pi\left(\frac {\sin nt}{\sin t}\right)^m\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 1{2i}
\int_0^{2\pi}
\left(\frac {e^{int}-e^{-int}}{e^{it}-e^{-it}}\right)^m
\cdot\frac 1{e^{it}}\; ie^{it}\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 1{2i}
\int_\gamma
\left(\frac {z^{n}-z^{-n}}{z-z^{-1}}\right)^m\cdot\frac 1z\;
\; dz
\\
&=
2\pi i\cdot\frac 1{2i}
\cdot\text{Residue of }
\frac 1z
\underbrace{\left(z^{n-1}+\dots z^{n-3}+\dots z^{-(n-3)}+z^{-(n-1)}\right)^m}_{P(n,m)}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Yes, this is the value of the integral. For instance in the computed example we need the residue for $$\frac 1z( z^6 + z^4 + z^2 + 1 + z^{-2} + z^{-4} + z^{-6} )^9\ ,$$it is the same as the coefficient in $z^0$ in $$( z^6 + z^4 + z^2 + 1 + z^{-2} + z^{-4} + z^{-6} )^9\ ,$$ i.e. the coefficient in $z^0$ = mid coefficient in  $$( z^3 + z^2 + z + 1 + z^{-1} + z^{-2} + z^{-3} )^9\ .$$ Same as taking the mid coefficient in $$( z^6 + z^5 + z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z+1)^9\ .$$ The $2\pi\; i \ /\ (2i)$ introduces a $\pi$ times this mid coefficient.